# ajax can't get response text from php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've created an html and a php file. The php links to a database (either my localhost or the university's database online), and the html uses AJAX to partially update a  tag's content:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>iNote</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function pullMore(){
        var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome,etc.
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{ // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4  /*&& xmlhttp.status ==200*/){
            document.getElementById("more").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","1.php",true);
    document.getElementById("more").innerHTML = "<p>notenter</p>";
    xmlhttp.send();

    }
    </script>        
    <div id="Checklist"></div>
    <div id="Note"></div>
    <div id="more" onclick="pullMore()">
    <p>Click to Replace Content Here</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

However, no matter how I modified the php's content, (even when I changed it to a simple `echo "<p>please show this!!</p>"`;), the `xmlhttp.status ==200` cannot be satisfied, and "notenter" is displayed on screen.

If I quote out the condition and leaving only `xmlhttp.readyState == 4`, the message in `<div>` would be replaced, but only by blank space...and if the php code is the full one for accessing database, EVERYTHING after echo, including all the codes and brackets, would be outputted...
Can anyone help me? I've been debugging for hours and still can't figure out where's the problem...Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the PHP script work when viewed in the browser or using `curl -v`? (With `curl -v` you can see the status code which might help to debug this.)

Comment: Also, does the output include the word echo?

Comment: It's working absolutely fine..I checked..

Comment: Any errors in the web service log? (httpd, IIS, etc)

Comment: What is the `xmlhttp.status` that you are getting?

Comment: @ethrbunny um...may I ask how to check the xmlhttp.status? Since I tried with ==200 and ==404, but both showed the "notenter" message, so the status is neither 200 nor 404..it seems

Comment: @ Joke_Sense10 I tried again by simply copying this code on webpage to a txt..but it still only shows blank and not the echo message.

Comment: @Robin Green Yes I have tried with both echo and print but neither seemed to work:(  I tried the php script using xampp's apache localhost, and it can both access my local database correctly and echo the contents...but I don't know why this html just can't read it...

Comment: Which browser? Have you tried with another browser?

Comment: Since you are (apparently) getting the 'readystate == 4' use a debugger to look at the value of 'status' when the call back occurs (or console.log if you are in chrome)